# Excel formula SUMIF problem with column counting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to sum values in column but sometimes there is no value written and i have only "yes" or "y" i want to sum it as 80 and my formula is not working.

I am trying to use

SUMIF(O2:O252;"*y*';O2:O252)
but i do not know hot to put the value 80 in it and count other values that are normally in the column too.

Comment: Can you add some simplified sample data to work with and wanted result just to show exactly what you are dealing with?

Comment: Yes of course so while doing a screen shot i have a column cointaining :
"20 |
21|
y|
yes|
no "

I need to count the values from the column WHEN there is a number or when there is y or yes. When i have y or yes i need to count it as (80)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
=COUNTIF(O2:O252;"y")*80 + SUM(O2:O252)
```

to count both "y" and "yes" try:

```
 SUM(COUNTIF(O2:O252;{"y","yes"})*80 + SUM(O2:O252)
```